# Storing multiple values in one MYSQL field

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am currently planning out how a table will look in MYSQL database.  I want to do something like the below, where plant1 and plant2 would be the columns, and then each of those plants would have characteristics assigned to them as you see below.

Is it possible to display info this way in MYSQL?

```
Array ( 
    [plant1] => Array ( 
                   [image_url] => http://www.example.com/image1.png 
                   [botanical_name] => Foo 
                   [common_name] => Bar 
    ),               
    [plant2] => Array ( 
                   [image_url] => http://www.example.com/image2.png
                   [botanical_name] => Foo 
                   [common_name] => Bar 
     )
```

Comment: No,read about first normal form.

Comment: In MySQL, you want each field to contain *one* value.  Have a look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Comment: Since you have common fields between them, why not have 3 columns (image_url, botanical_name, common_name), and an identifying 4th column (plant1 vs plant2).  I imagine it would be less stressful than having to parse every column for the various values every time you query it.

Comment: Don't use this design, it will lead to horrible complications in the future. You'll need to parse every cell and won't be able to create simple queries.

Comment: Don't do it! It always causes so much work and can lead to bad performance

Comment: @DMortensen, would you mind explaining in more detail about your solution, but know that in this case I do not want Plant1 or Plant2 to be used as a row name.

Comment: Well then in that case you don't need a 4th column, just using the 3 columns would suffice if you don't want further granularity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i don't suggest that, but you can insert php array to that field and then parse it in php when you are getting data from database. So the content of that field would be like that:

```
$plant1 = array('plant1' => array('image_url' => 'http://www.example.com/image1.png', 'botanical_name' => 'Foo', 'common_name' => 'Bar'));
$plant2 = array('plant2' => array('image_url' => 'http://www.example.com/image2.png', 'botanical_name' => 'Foo', 'common_name' => 'Bar'));
```

You can insert `$plant1` `$plant2` to your mysql fields and then print it like this to get wanted result:

```
print_r(array_merge($mysql_plant1, $mysql_plant2));
```

Function `array_merge` connects arrays together.

Comment: Yes, this is probably something I would be willing to do, considering that this application will be very small, and never end up being more complicated than this. Thanks for showing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it storing as a serialized value (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) but it's not a good idea.

For that you will have to create another table to store the caracteristics of each plant like:

```
**plants**
id_plant
name

**plants_ccharacteristics**
id_plant_characteristic
fk_plant
name
value
```

In that way you can store it properly.

As an extra point, that structure you want to store looks quite good for use NoSQL databases like MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

Your table design is flawed. What you should have is Plant being a row, with each item in the array being a column in the plants table.

If you need Plants to be a column in another table, then assign the first column of the plants table to be a unique, auto-incrementing key and then put that key in the column of the other table. Eg:

```
**Garden_Plants**
gp_key
gp_garden_id
gp_plant_id <-- p_id from Plants_Table

**Plants_Table**
p_id
p_botanical_name
p_common_name
p_image_url
```

Answer (score 0):

you would have a table called plants,  this would have a related table called plantDetails  that has a referencing ID from the plant in question.

this would give 1 plant, with multiple references

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem optimised for querying the database, however if you have a specific reason for doing it this way please let us know..

**A more optimised solution:**

Have a table called Plants, with fields ID, image_url, botanical_name, common_name.

Store all plants in that table. ID is a unique Identifier for that plant, probably set with autonumber so cannot be duplicated

If you need to store some kind of relationship between 2 plants, have a table called plant_relationships with fields for something like plant_ID_1 and plant_ID_2

You can then query your full list of plants directly, or query the relationships table to find plants related to other plants

Answer (score 0):

If you want multiple values in one mysql field, i would suggest to put your information in one string before storing it in the database. Each substring need to be separated by a character that will not be used in the substrings.

```
$value1 = aaa
$value2 = bbb
$value3 = ccc

$valueAll = aaa:bbb:ccc
```

When you get the data out of the DB, you will need to split the string with the : or the other character selected.